# alignment of equations in align environment with itemize

Tags: equations, amsmath

I am using `amsmath` environment and I want to align equations with multiple `align` environment. An example can be seen in the figure:
[image]

Now what i want is shown in arrows. I want i=0,..2n in eq 2.4.2 to shift leftwards so this text is aligned with the text of equation 2.4.1. at the same time i also want eq 2.4.3 to be aligned with eq 2.4.2. an example code is given below:

```
         \documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}

           \begin{enumerate}
            \item Form $2n+1$ sample points (also known as sigma points) vectors $x^{(i)}$  as follows:
            \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
            x^{(i)}=\begin{cases}\bar{x} & \text{$i=0$} \\
            \bar{x}+\left(\sqrt{(n+\lambda)P}\right)^T_i & \text{$i=1,\cdots,n$} \\[1.2ex]
            \bar{x}-\left(\sqrt{(n+\lambda)P}\right)^T_i & \text{$i=n+1,\cdots,2n$}
            \end{cases}
            \end{aligned}
            \end{equation}
            \item Transform sigma points:
            \begin{align}
            y^{(i)} &= h(x^{(i)}) & \text{$i=0,\cdots,2n$}
            \end{align}
            \item Approximate mean and covariance as given below:
            \begin{align}
            {y}_u &=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}W^{(m)}_i y^{(i)}\notag\\
            P_u &=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}W^{(c)}_i \left(y^{(i)}-y_u\right)\left(y^{(i)}-y_u\right)^T
            \end{align}
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside different math environments, it is highly impossible to do that alignment. But in the same environment (`align` here)  it is possible with some manual intervention.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \noindent Some text follows
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Form $2n+1$ sample points (also known as sigma points) vectors $x^{(i)}$  as follows:
        \begin{align}            
            \qquad  x^{(i)}&=\begin{cases}\bar{x} & \text{$i=0$} \\
            \bar{x}+\left(\sqrt{(n+\lambda)P}\right)^T_i & \text{$i=1,\cdots,n$} \\[1.2ex]
            \bar{x}-\left(\sqrt{(n+\lambda)P}\right)^T_i & \text{$i=n+1,\cdots,2n$}
            \end{cases}          
            %
            \intertext{\item Transform sigma points:}
            y^{(i)} &= h(x^{(i)}) \hphantom{\left(\sqrt{(n+\lambda)P}\right) y^{(i\,}}  \text{$i=0,\cdots,2n$}
            %
            \intertext{\item Approximate mean and covariance as given below:}
            {y}_u &=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}W^{(m)}_i y^{(i)}\notag\\
            P_u &=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}W^{(c)}_i \left(y^{(i)}-y_u\right)\left(y^{(i)}-y_u\right)^T
     \end{align}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `\quad` in the beginning of first equation and `\hphantom` for some alignment. The equations are not guaranteed to be centred. If your equations go beyond a page break, you may add `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks ! It works, I guess it is not a good idea to use different math environments in this scenario. It was a bit tricky to solve this...

Comment: @Umz Glad it helped :-)

Comment: It looks so wrong to me that the other `\item`s are nested within the math environment... but even within beamer and several `\uncover` commands, this solution works flawlessly!